# js replace regex first letter to uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have XML content like this

```
<abc:content><bcd:position>Just text: node not need to replace</abc:content>
```

and I need replace it with

```
<abc:Content><bcd:Position>Just text: node not need to replace</abc:Content>
```

In SublimeText or Notepad++ I can replace it with regex, if I search for

```
:. or :\b(\w) or :\b.
```

and replace it with

```
:\U$1
```

It works fine. But I cant use

```
string.replace(/:\b./g , ':\U$1');
```

this dont work correctly! If I try use ':$1'.toUpperCase() its still dont give right result - This used in other questions, and dont work for me.
Help me, please!

Comment: Is the variable js your string value? If not: use the replace method on your string.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: I always convert it to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a replacement function:

```js
var xml = '<abc:content><bcd:position></abc:content>';

var xml2 = xml.replace(/:\w/g, function(matched) {
  return matched.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(xml2);
```

Bear in mind that using regex is not a very good idea here as it will also replace any other letters in your XML that come right after a colon:

```js
var xml = '<abc:content><bcd:position>Just text:node not need to replace</bcd:position></abc:content>';

var xml2 = xml.replace(/:\w/g, function(matched) {
  return matched.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(xml2);
```

Comment: Its very close, but i dont need to replace text nodes. But now I thik I can live with it. I will use match '/b' not /w

Comment: @AlexLatro Yeah, I specifically pointed out that that was a problem with using regex for this. There are better ways to transform XML (XSLT, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function callback for the replacement, like so:

```
var js = '<abc:content><bcd:position></abc:content>';
js.replace(/:(\w)/g, function(c) { return c.toUpperCase() });
//"<abc:Content><bcd:Position></abc:Content>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "<abc:content><bcd:position></abc:content>";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "Source: " + str.replace(/\</g, '&lt').replace(/\>/g, '&gt');
document.body.appendChild(div);
str = str.replace(/:(\b)./g , function(x){return x.toUpperCase();});
div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "Result: " + str.replace(/\</g, '&lt').replace(/\>/g, '&gt');
document.body.appendChild(div);
```